# Extending SharePoint On Prem CSOM

Tags: development, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a requirement that needs me to make a web part inside a SharePoint On Prem site. This web part needs to speak to an API via ajax. The site does not have OAuth and uses Kerbesos Authentication, so if I host a API on a different web application the ajax call comes but not authorised.

I would like to extend the CSOM, is this possible and a supported solution?

Another alternative would be to create an Application in the SharePoint IIS Site (in IIS click Add Application) and add my MVC Web API Site there, since its in the same web application authentication is maintained from logging into sharepoint.

Or is there a way I can share Kerberos Authenication accross web applications? the Web application can be on the same domain just different subdomains (ie sharepoint.MyDomain.com and Apps.MyDomain.com)